# 2 bishops versus a lone king

Tags: strategy, chess, game, checkerboard, board-games

There are 4 pieces on the board, the white and black kings, as well as 2 white bishops (on differently colored squares).

The only way a stalemate occurs is if the black king is not in check, but cannot make a move. (No threefold repetition, timer, etc.) Remaining rules are same as chess.

Assuming perfect play by both players, give the position of the board where white wins, but requires the maximum possible moves to do a checkmate.

Comment: So far, for all of the difficult positions that I can think of, the engine can force checkmate in 14 moves. So, if someone finds one that takes more than 14 moves, post it!

Comment: Is there a way too some this without a computerized search or consulting a tablebase?

Comment: @xnor It requires a chess engine and some intuition and apparently lots of time. ghosts, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Wouldn't the max be around 50 (within some 3 moves)?

Comment: Wikipedia says "With the side with the bishops to move, checkmate can be forced in at most nineteen moves," so there's that

Comment: Good work Lopsy. Now to see if Stockfish can take that position from wikipedia and force checkmate in less than 19...

Comment: Although I answered it, it took only a couple of Google searches; plus this is not on-topic, given that humans cannot reasonably be expected to "solve it",i.e. demonstrate how a given number of moves is the best. Sorry, OP, but -1.

Comment: On second thought, it may be possible and interesting to find the best number of moves for any n by n board. But my vote is locked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it might be more at home on Chess.SE.

Comment: **Okay, everybody** I was not interested in people using computers to figure it out. Isn't there some basic strategy used to corner the lone king somehow, so you can manually figure out the solution? Generally I just make a barrier of 2 diagonal lines, and keep reducing the space available for the black king to move. If computing is the only way to solve, I don't mind migrating or closing the question.

Comment: Questions should not be put on hold because they might be more on-topic elsewhere. If they are on-topic here, we should keep them.

Comment: @Emrakul The problem is that there is, as far as I can tell, nothing of a puzzle about this, especially given that answers suggest that OP's question in the comment above yours - 'is there a logical approach to achieving the minimal number of moves?' - has a negative answer. I think there are valid chess questions for this site, and valid optimization questions for this site, but this is neither of those.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki then it should be closed because it's off-topic here, NOT "because it might be more at home on Chess.SE."

Answer (score 10):

The answer is 19 moves.
The first link in a search for "two bishops longest mate" shows this site: http://www.gilith.com/chess/endgames/kbb_k.html

Checking the Nalimov tablebase on this site: http://chessok.com/?page_id=361
shows that the position indeed requires 19 moves.

The position is: White: Ba4, Bd8, Ka1, Black: Kb4.